# USB Barcode Scanner Serial won't work just freezes/hangs

Tags: raspbian, python, input-device

I am trying to build a basic POS System, naturally I would have a usb barcode scanner and a simple code from [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/USB-Barcode-Scanner-Raspberry-Pi/) to start.

Everything went well from scanning using serial to DB entry and then GUI. But after a reboot, serial doesn't work anymore. It just hangs without releasing the serial output.

What I tried:

-Enable/Disable Serial

-Switching from USB keyboard to serial mode on barcode scanner to make  sure it still works

-Switching from hdraws 0 and 2

-Reflashing card with OS clean install of everything

-Used a different pi

-Tried the basic code of just printing the serial output
   - sudo apt-get install update and upgrade

Help, I dont know anymore whats not working, this is supposed to be basic setup. I think the problem is the serial? or the scanner? I'm out of ideas already.

Also the last error I caught "miraculously" as I waited until it releases an output was an I/O Input/output error. This is why I think it  might be the serial?

My setup:

[image: mysetup]

Comment: `Switching from hdraws 0 and 2` why? what does `ls /dev/hidraw*` output?

Comment: if a new install (obviously re-doing ALL instructions in the link you provided) and multiple pi's all exhibit the same issue, then the most likely problem is with the scanner - but, does the scanner work on a non-pi in keyboard mode?

Comment: @JaromandaX about the hdraws, sorry, I searched it up, hdraw0 is made when the usb scanner is plugged in so it was a futile effort for that/

Keyboard mode works on the Pi's and it gets the barcode, correct me if I am wrong but I can't fetch that for use right? Which is why we use serial? it just displays.

If  there was a way to fetch the barcode read in keyboard mode, then it should fix the problem.

But currently I think it should be read as serial isnt it?

Comment: can't python read keyboard input? though in my opinion, serial mode is the better option - except it doesn't work of course

Comment: @JaromandaX I think it doesn't as I tried fetching it as a workaround, I tried finding that variable that represent the barcode being printed on the interface, but there's nothing, which means there isn't a variable for me to play around with.

Comment: so, when scanning in keyboard mode, if you're directly on the pi (not SSH) the bardcode doesn't appear on the command line?

Comment: when scanning in keyboard mode, the barcode appears on the commandline. But strangely enough it seemed that the code doesn't have anything related to it, I tried adding flags but they won't display which means that the code maybe had nothing to do with it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after reboot, serial doesn't work. It just hangs without releasing the
>   serial output.
>
> Enable/Disable Serial
>
> Switching from USB keyboard to serial mode on barcode scanner to make
>   sure it still works
>
> problem is the serial? or the scanner? I'm out of ideas already

Well, if you said the barcode reader works OK.  Then there are two possibilities:

1. Rpi serial hardware/software is not OK.
2. Both Rpi and bard code reader are OK.  But they crash.

So first thing first is to make sure your Rpi hardware/software is OK.  You might like to read my answers to the questions below suggesting newbies how to do the following checking:

1. Rpi UART is OK.
2. Rpi python UART is also OK

After the above two things are OK.  Then check Rpi python interface with Arduino, bardcode devices etc.

[Serial to Arduino totally non-responsive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96184/serial-to-arduino-totally-non-responsive/96264#96264)

[Serial Communication from Raspbian using Python to Arduino](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/serial-communication-from-raspbian-using-python-to-arduino)

Comment: thanks, I did just the same! figured out the serial wasnt working and was defective when I replaced it it was fine. Takeaway was that to make a basic sample code and if it doesnt work, check the hardware first before debugging code~!

Comment: @Firiyuu77 I am glad to hear that you solved the problem.  Happy barcoding! :)