# How can Rpi listen to a GPS module?

Tags: raspbian, gps

Hi guys i'm quite new to raspberry pi and i'm having trouble with a GPS module that i have bought. 
https://wiki.52pi.com/index.php/USB-Port-GPS_Module_SKU:EZ-0048#Trouble_Shooting
i go to installing all the packages required for the module and begin to testing the to see if it picks up a latitude/longitude and this is what occurs.

[image]

when i check the status of the module it seems to be fine showing the following:

[image]
However lastly when i check the serial to see if it is receiving any data this occurs

[image]
i have been at this for hours and i'm not sure if the module itself is the problem or its me. If anyone can help that would be great

Comment: Do you have it connected via serial port, or via USB?

Comment: i did tried both of these and got no results. im sticking with the usb as it is easier to handle

Comment: Good choice! Your antenna is outdoors I assume?

Comment: yeah i have been sitting outside for while, it is very cloudy, i have gotten the time to show up and it updates correctly, from the first screen shot, however the rest is the same.

Comment: Ah, let me see. There are many possibilities: (1) Your serial hardware might not have been properly set up.  I would recommend first do a serial loopback test. (test program included in my answer to the following question: "Rpi UART GPSD to GPS Module Connection Problem":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/rpi-uart-to-gps-module-connection-problem, (2) The signal in your place is too weak, or too noisy.  You might like to use a long antenna, and also use lipo power bank to reduce noise. You might like to compare how I use GPSD.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i received a long antenna device today and have i might hook it up tomorrow when its a clear day, ill have a look at your thread as well, for the price the module i bought is "garbo"

Comment: As I suggested in my answer, you don't need to first connect Rpi UART in the preliminary setting up. In other words, your first step is (1) Try to get a "fix", to make the blue LED blinking. The second step is (2)  To make sure serial is OK by doing loopback test to make sure that USB or on board Serial is working, then (3) Install GPSD and try the basic tests CGPS and XGPS (See Appendix M to compare my  e sample output).  Good luck, cheers.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: And if you have completed all the above three steps, getting data from the GPS module, then perhaps you can do (4) Use python, instead of CGPS and CGPS utilities, to store and process the GPS text and graphics data. I saw that your last two screen captures seem to dig into the ttyUSB and socket thing, which I think is too low level, too tedious, too messy to explore. Of course it is just my opinion, and I am a newbie in GPS, after all, though I have about 5 hobbyist years playing with Rpi.

Comment: Hi @antos. I am sorry that before I made my answer, I did not read the troubleshooting guide you are referring. Just now I read it again and found that you are doing what the guide says, playing at the socket level. I need to read that guide again and see if I can make more comments. Cheers.

Comment: I read the Quectel L80-R setup and troubleshooting guide and found that they are also using GPSD (I am not surprised, because GPSD is a well developed huge project and so everybody is using it). The python examples are also good, I need to read carefully one more time to see if I can give more comments. PS - My setup though also using GPSD, but then CGPS and XGPS etc, which is not the way the L80-R guide goes. So I think it is not a good reference for you to use pythong to get data. / to continue, ...

Comment: Though my first suggested steps are still good, get a fix first, check serial (the guide uses a direct check at socket level) is still good. Below are the docs I read so far: (1) Quectel L80-R USB-Port-GPS Module SKU:EZ-0048 
https://wiki.52pi.com/index.php/USB-Port-GPS_Module_SKU:EZ-0048#Trouble_Shooting

(2) L80-R Hardware Design GPS Module Series Rev. L80-R_Hardware_Design_V1.2 Date: 2016-04-22
https://wiki.52pi.com/images/e/ed/Quectel_L80-R_Hardware_Design_V1.2.pdf, to continue, ...

Comment: (3) Quectel L80-R Compact GPS Module Integrated with Patch Antenna 
https://wiki.52pi.com/images/7/73/Quectel_L80-R_GPS_Specification_V1.0.pdf. / to continue, ...

Comment: I casually searched AliExpress and found the following product page, but no document at all. Please let me know if you have other good links with good docs. "AliExpress 2pcs/lot DIYmall Quectel L80-R Compact GPS module integrated with Patch antenna for Acquisition and tracking - US$14":
https://www.aliexpress.com/i/33021219197.html. Cheers.

Comment: I was using the following module:(4) "AliExpress GPS + Beidou Two-mode positioning module - US$24":
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32978748359.html. But I have not played with it for a long while. Let me see if I can find it in my junk box and set it up and start playing again. Ah bed time, see you tomorrow.

Comment: @tlfon01 yeah thanks for all the help i'm going to read and go through what you initially sent now, and i'm going to give another go outside today, ill find somewhere out in the open and give it a go. ill keep you updated, ill be working on this thing the entire day today

Comment: @tlflon, yes i finally got a fix with another hour or so playing around. i did some extra research and apparently GPS modules do not work well with tin and tin roofing. since that being everyones roof in my area, after some walking around outside i finally got a fix, not completely ideal but at-least i now know it works. Thanks so much for all the resources they truly helped. Have a good day!

Comment: How nice to hear the good news.  My test site is some 20 metres down a concrete well.  I guess there are mild steel rods within the concrete walls, but radio signals can penetrate with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question***

1. The OP is quite new to Rpi.
2. He has a common GPS module QueCtel L80-R
3. He has GPSD loaded and listening at the GPSD socket.
4. He has two problems:

   a. *"$ cgps" does not show any GPS data*.

   b. *"$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0" does not show any serial transmission signals either*.

How to fix it?

---

[image: l80-r 2]

---

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Answer***

*Update 2020jun17hkt2143*

I have found the following gps-python sample code for Rpi4 and uBlox GPS module

[python-gps sample codes, Raspberry Pi 4 + uBlox GPS module (uart)](https://gist.github.com/wolfg1969/4653340)

Now I am going to test the sample code using bot uBlox Neo M7 and M8 modules.

---

*Update 2020jun15hkt1231*

I found the user guide the OP is following is some 4 years old (2016), so should be a bit out of date (For example, the UART CP2012 driver recommended might not be good any more, as last year I tested CH340 is much better, and old 2012 drivers for Win7 are no longer working for new Win10 version).

I also suspected that new GPS modules on sale in these two years should have a better performance than old versions.  So I bought two more GPS modules Neo M7 and M8 to compare.  To my surprise, the fixing times of the 3 GPS modules do not have any substantial difference. So I concluded that the OP's Quectel L80-R GPS should still be up to date and work OK, at least for hobbyist projects like mine.

---

[image: gps tests 1]

---

---

***Short Answer***

I would suggest the OP to do the following testing/troubleshooting procedures:

1. Install the three most basic GPS programs: ***gpsd, gpsd-client, python-gps***, all three programs must be of same version ***3.17-7***. See Appendix D for more details.
2. ***Enable/start/status GPSD***, to make sure the software has been installed properly.  In case there are installation errors, it is important to remove old installations, or use a fresh SD image to try again. It is easier to do the installation using Desktop GUI.  I have tried with Rpi3B+ and Rpi4B, both with raspbian buster. See Part C below for more details.

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Long Answer***

*Contents*

1. Part A - Setting up the module and trying a get a fix
2. Part B - Checking out serial hardware /dev/ttyS0 and /dev/ttyUSB0
3. Part C - Installing GPSD and testing utilities gpsmon, cgps, and xgps
4. Part D - Installing GPS Python library and testing python NMEA 0183 programs
5. Part E - Discussion and recommendation
6. References
7. Appendices
8. Program Listings
9. Figures

---

*Part A - Setting up the GPS module and trying to get a fix*

First thing first is to set up the GPS module and try to get a fix (Figures 1 ~ 3).

I placed the antenna about 15cm outside the window and powered up.  As usual, the first fix takes about 1 to 2 minutes. The subsequent power off power on fixes takes from 15 sec to 45 sec, with an average of 30 seconds.  This fixing timing is similar to last time of 2019may.  So I quickly concluded that setup and fixing is reliable.

This is [the imgur fixing video](https://imgur.com/gallery/ft3wq86).

---

And the photo.

*Notes:*

1. When power is on, blue LED is turned on and steady.  When there is a fix, blue LED blinks as shown in the above Imgur video.
2. The serial cable is not connected in this fixing test.  Serial cable test is the next step.

[image: gps antenna]

---

*Part B - Checking out the serial cable*

I used my [serial loopback program v0.99](https://penzu.com/p/f2cb232e) (Ref 12) to verify that Rpi's on board Tx/Rx wiring and software are more or less OK.

Next step is to install GPSD.

---

*Part C - Installing GPSD*

I quickly read the [Quectel L80RE GPS Module User Guide](https://penzu.com/p/f962753d) and follow the
instructions there to install the following:

***gpsd, gpsd-clients, and python-gps***,

and starting running it.  Everything was smooth, except a couple of errors during installation.  I could enable, start, status without any problem but cgps does not seem to run properly, such as indicating no fix, though there are actually a fix.

[image: gpsd install]

---

The above installations using CLI terminal commands *$sudo apt-get install* were not smooth, with a couple of error messages. So I used buster Desktop GUI and installed the similar gpsd and client packages ***v3.17-7*** as shown below:

---

[image: gpsd and clients installation]

---

[image: setup1]

---

[image: setup2]

---

[image: setup3]

---

[image: setup4]

---

[image: setup5]

---

*Part D - Installin GPS Python library and testing python demo programs*

(15) [Quectel GPS Module User Guide Reading Summary V0.3 (Python Demo Programs)](https://penzu.com/p/4493416e)

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [Quectel L80-R GPS Module User Guide](https://wiki.52pi.com/index.php/USB-Port-GPS_Module_SKU:EZ-0048#Trouble_Shooting)

(2) [Quectel L80-R Hardware Design GPS Module Series Rev. L80-R_Hardware_Design_V1.2 Date: 2016](https://wiki.52pi.com/images/e/ed/Quectel_L80-R_Hardware_Design_V1.2.pdf)

(3) [Quectel L80-R Compact GPS Module Integrated with Patch Antenna - 2015](https://wiki.52pi.com/images/7/73/Quectel_L80-R_GPS_Specification_V1.0.pdf)

(4) [Quectel L80-R Compact GPS module integrated with Patch antenna for Acquisition and tracking - DIYMall US$14](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/33021219197.html)

(5) [Quectel GPS Module User Guide Reading Summary V0.1](https://penzu.com/p/f962753d)

(6) [Quectel GPS Module User Guide Reading Summary V0.2](https://penzu.com/p/1194ea75)

(7) [Quectel GPS Module User Guide Reading Summary V0.3 (Python Demo Programs)](https://penzu.com/p/4493416e)

(8) [SkyTraq ATK1218-BD (ATK-S1216) GPS/BD dual mode GPS module - Risym ¥98](https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?)

(9) [SkyTraq GPS + Beidou Two-mode positioning module - US$24](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32978748359.html)

(10) [SkyTraq Products - SkyTraq](https://www.skytraq.com.tw/products/products.html)

(11) [SkyTraq S1216 [renamed S1218-BD] Family GNSS Module Data Sheet - SkyTraq](http://www.skytraq.com.tw/datasheet/S1216V8_v0.9.pdf)

(12) [Serial Port Loopback Test Program V0.60 - tlfong01 2019apr15 Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/serial-communication-from-raspbian-using-python-to-arduino/96535#96535)

(13) [Serial LoopBack Program v0.98 -tlfong01 2020jan08](https://penzu.com/p/49c560cf)

(14) [Serial Port Multiple Problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98393/options-to-add-20-uart-to-rpi)

(15) [Serial UART LoopBack Program v0.99 tlfong01  2020jun03hkt1510](https://penzu.com/p/f2cb232e)

(16) [Rpi3 Old Driver Serail Cable Test Results - HL340, PL2302, CP2102 might not work)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96697/how-many-serial-ports-are-on-the-pi-3)

(17) [Raspberry Pi Serial (UART) Tutorial - Roland Pelayo 2018jun12](https://www.teachmemicro.com/raspberry-pi-serial-uart-tutorial/)

(18) [NMEA 0183 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183)

(19) [NMEA User Guide](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm)

(20) [gpsd_json — gpsd request/response protocol](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsd_json.html)

(21) [gpsd(8) manual pages](http://man.docs.sk/8/gpsd.html)

(22) [libgps(3) manual pages](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libgps-dev/libgps.3.en.html)

(23) [gspmon manual pages - ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gpsmon.1.html)

(24) [gpsmon forum discussion - rpi.org.forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=185329#p1171448)

(25) [BerryGPS Tutorial Setup Guide](https://ozzmaker.com/berrygps-setup-guide-raspberry-pi/)

(26) [MakerPro Daniel Hertz Tutorial: How to Use a GPS Receiver With Rpi 4 - 2020feb03](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-use-a-gps-receiver-with-raspberry-pi-4)

(27) [MakerPro Daniel Hertz Tutorial: How to read GPS data with Python on Rpi - Daniel Hertz, MakerPro 2020feb24](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-read-gps-data-with-python-on-a-raspberry-pi)

(28) [How can Rpi connect a GPS module? Rpi.StackExchange Q&A - tlfong01 2019](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/rpi-uart-gpsd-to-gps-module-connection-problem)

(28) [Fixing: GPS TTFF/TTSF (Time To First Fix, Time To Subsequent Fix) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix)

(29) [Fixing: Weather - Can an overcast sky prevent your GPS from working? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-an-overcast-sky-prevent-your-GPS-from-working)

(30) [Fixing: Weather - Does heavy cloud cover affect GPS reception? - Rich Owings 2005sep10](https://gpstracklog.com/2005/09/does_cloud_cove.html)

(31) [GPS vs GNSS: Understanding PNT Satellite Systems - Masterclock 2019jan14](https://www.masterclock.com/company/masterclock-inc-blog/gps-vs-gnss)

(32) [AliExpress Neo6M GPS Module Catalog](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-gps-module-neo-6m.html)

(33) [TaoBao NEO-6M APM2 GPS Module ¥14](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.269c3ad4vKmLJZ&id=563083169021)

(34) [The 10 Best Diy Gps Module of 2020 (Beginners Guide) Josie Schinner 2019sep09](https://afiavillage.com/diy-gps-module/)

(35) [The 8 Best Arduino GPS Modules 2019 - 2019Sep](https://wiki.ezvid.com/best-arduino-gps-modules)

(36) [python-gps sample codes, Raspberry Pi 4 + u-blox GPS module (uart)](https://gist.github.com/wolfg1969/4653340)

(37) [Getting GPS to work on Rpi3B - dragino.com](https://wiki.dragino.com/index.php?title=Getting_GPS_to_work_on_Raspberry_Pi_3_Model_B)

(38) [NEO-6M GPS u-blox Datasheet and Protocol Specification - ublox 2013apr18](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox6_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%28GPS.G6-SW-10018%29_Public.pdf)

(39) [NEO-6M GPS ESP32 How to boost receiving speed - Victor, Medium 2020jan12](https://medium.com/@cglabs/neo-6m-gps-howto-boost-data-receiving-speed-neo-6-neo-7-neo-8-487275eff1c6)

(40) [Neo-6M GPS Arduino How to boost receiver speed - 2017apr14](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=470763.0)

(41) [Neo-6/7/8 Interface Manuals](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product-resources?keywords=protocol)

(42) [NEO-6 u-blox 6 GPS Modules Data Sheet - ublox](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/NEO-6_DataSheet_(GPS.G6-HW-09005).pdf)

(43) [NEO-6M Product Sheet and References - WaveShare](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/UART_GPS_NEO-6M)

(44) [NEO-6M User Manual - WaveShare](https://www.terraelectronica.ru/pdf/show?pdf_file=%2Fz%2FDatasheet%2FU%2FUART%20GPS%20NEO-6M%20User%20Manual.pdf)

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - GPS Module Pinout and Block Diagram*

[image: gps module pinout]

---

*Appendix B - NMEA 0183 Message Format*

[image: nmea0183msg 1]

---

*Appendix C GPSD Commands Summary V0.1*

*Serial Commands*

$ dmesg | grep tty
[ 0.001609] console [tty1] enabled
[ 0.092061] 3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[ 0.594855] console [ttyAMA0] enabled

ttyS0 = Serial for Raspberry Pi 3, ttyAMA0 = Serial for all other Raspberry Pi
'serial0' is assigned as an alias to either of the above devices. This makes the device a lot easier to remember.

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -l /dev/serial0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Aug 28 12:49 /dev/serial0 -> ttyS0

*Install gpsd*

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo reboot
$ sudo apt-get install gpsd-clients gpsd -y
$ usdo apt-get install gpsmon

*To enable/start/stop/disable/kill gpsd*

$ sudo systemctl enable gpsd.socket
$ sudo systemctl start gpsd.socket
$ sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
$ sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket
$ sudo killall gpsd

*Gpsd config file*

$ sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd
Look for DEVICES="" and change it to
DEVICES="/dev/serial0"

*3 Ways To read GPS data*

*1. cat*
$ cat /dev/serial0

*2. minicom*

$ sudo apt-get install minicom -y
$ minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/serial0

*3. Screen*

$ sudo apt-get install screen
$ screen /dev/serial0 9600

*To view GPS data with gpsmon or cgps, if gpsd not aut started at boot*

$ sudo gpsd /dev/serial0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
$ sudo gpsmon
$ sudo cgps
$ sudo xcgs

*To profile on a GPS.  A gnuplot scatter graph of 100 samples*

$ gpsprof | gnuplot -persist

*A summary of some NMEA sentences*

$GPVTG  Vector track and Speed over the Ground

$GPGGA  GGA - essential fix data which provide 3D location and accuracy data.

$GPGLL  GLL - Geographic Latitude and Longitude

$GPGSA  GSA - details on the nature of the fix

$GPGSV  Detailed satelite data

$GPRMC  RMC - The recommended minimum

---

*Appendix D - Installing and setting up GPSD on buster release 2020may23*

[image: Installing GPSD on buster release 2020may23]

---

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Program Listings***

*(A) Serial Lookback Test v0.6 - 2019apr08 tlfong01*

```
# uart_test06 tlfong01 2019apr08hkt1603 ***
# https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/rpi-python-serial-test-program/96535#96535

# uart_test06 tlfong01 2019apr08hkt1603 ***

# Computer = Rpi3B+
# Linux    = $ hostnamectl = raspberrypi Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) Linux 4.14.34-v7+ arm 
# Python   = >>> sys.version = 3.5.3 Jan 19 2017

# Test 1   - repeatWriteBytes() - UART port repeatedly send out bytes.  
# Function - Repeat many times sending bytes, pause after each bytes.

# Test 2   - loopBackTest() - UART port send and receive bytes.
# Function - Send one bytes to TX, wait some time (Note 1), then read bytes back from RX. 
# Setup    - Connet Tx pin to Rx pin to form a loop.

# Note 1
# Bolutek BlueTooth BC04 needs at least 10mS to respond

from   time import sleep
import serial

serialPort0 = serial.Serial(port = '/dev/serial0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout= 1)

def setSerialPortBaudRate(serialPort, baudrate):
    serialPort.baudrate = baudrate
    return

def serialPortWriteBytes(serialPort, writeBytes):
    serialPort.write(writeBytes)
    return

def serialPortReadBytes(serialPort, maxBytesLength):
    readBytes = serialPort.read(maxBytesLength)
    return readBytes

def serialPortWriteWaitReadBytes(serialPort, writeBytes, maxBytesLength, waitTime):
    serialPort.flushInput()
    serialPort.flushOutput()
    serialPort.write(writeBytes)
    sleep(waitTime) 
    readBytes = serialPortReadBytes(serialPort, maxBytesLength)
    print('        bytes written = ', writeBytes) 
    print('        bytes read    = ', readBytes)
    return readBytes

def repeatWriteBytes(serialPort, writeBytes, pauseTimeBetweenBytes, repeatCount):
    print('       Begin repeatWriteOneByte(), ...')   
    for i in range(repeatCount):
        serialPortWriteBytes(serialPort, writeBytes)                
        sleep(pauseTimeBetweenBytes)
    print('       End   repeatWriteOneByte().')
    return

def serialPortLoopBack(serialPort, writeBytes, maxBytesLength, waitTime): 
    print('        Begin serialPortLoopBack() [Remember to connect Tx to Rx!] , ...')
    serialPortWriteWaitReadBytes(serialPort, writeBytes, maxBytesLength, waitTime)     
    print('        End   serialPortLoopBack(), ...')
    return

setSerialPortBaudRate(serialPort0, 9600)
#repeatWriteBytes(serialPort0, b'AT\r\n', 0.01, 200000000)
serialPortLoopBack(serialPort0, b'AT\r\n', 32, 0.030)

''' Sample output  tlfong01 2019apr0801
>>> 
=== RESTART: /home/pi/Python_Programs/test1193/uart_test02_2019apr0801.py ===
        Begin serialPortLoopBack() [Remember to connect Tx to Rx!] , ...
        bytes written =  b'AT\r\n'
        bytes read    =  b'AT\r\n'
        End   serialPortLoopBack(), ...
>>>
'''

# End
```

---

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Figures***

*Fig 1 - GPS Module Setup 1*

[image: gps setup 2]

---

*Fig 2 - GPS Module Setup 2*

[image: gps setup 3]

---

*Fig 3 - GPS Module Setup 3*

[image: gps setup 4]

---

*Fig 4 - GPS Testing Site*

[image: gps test site]

---

Answer (score 1):

`cat /dev/ttyUSB0` will only work if the baud rate is set correctly on both sides of the UART which may or may not be the case. Check the documentation for your module to see if there are any instructions regarding the baud rate settings.

Also, cheap GPS modules are not going to give you any meaningful data until they acquire a fix, and must be tested [outside](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98864/33476). Do a test outdoors, preferably with a laptop, and wait for at least 12.5 minutes before trying to communicate with the module.