# Rpi Thonny python IDE has a problem running Pynmea2 GPS program. How to fix it?

Tags: pi-4, terminal, gps

I can't run this gps program in Thonny IDE. How come I can only run this gps program when I run it in the terminal without sudo? Is there a way to fix this?
EDIT: The part without the print(gps) and the missing colon is a typo

```
import serial
import time 
import string
import pynmea2
while True:
    port=”/dev/ttyAMA0”
    ser=serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)
    dataout = pynmea2.NMEAStreamReader()
    newdata=ser.readline()

    if newdata[0:6] == “$GPRMC”
        newmsg = pynmea2.prase(newdata)
        lat = newmsg.latitude
        lng = newmsg.longitude
        gps = “Latitude= ” + str(lat) + “ and Longitude= ” + str(lng)
```

When I run it in Thonny IDE, it only says Run gps.py with nothing below.

EDIT:
This code from @tlfong01 in link #1 seemed to do the trick.

```
import serial
import time
import string
import pynmea2

port="/dev/ttyAMA0"
ser=serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600 ,   parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,

  stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,

  bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,)


while True:
        dataout = pynmea2.NMEAStreamReader()
        newdata=ser.readline()
        if (newdata[0:6] == b"$GPRMC"):
                newmsg=pynmea2.parse(newdata.decode("utf-8"))

                lat=newmsg.latitude
                lng=newmsg.longitude

                gps = "Latitude=" + str(lat) + "and Longitude=" + str(lng)

                print(gps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Question***

Rpi Thonny python IDE has a problem running a pynmea2 GPS program.  How to fix it?

---

***Answer***

*Part A - Troubleshooting notes*

1. My Thonny is python 3, but your program is python2, so I need to format a bit:

   (a) double quote to single quote,

   (b) add colon after if statement.

---

2. Thonny then gave "import pynmea2" error, so I used Thonny package management tools to install pynmea2, then I can run the program without any error message.

---

3. Your program seems to read the pynmea2's reader output OK, but then you check the new data without any decision, such as:

   (a) If cannot read GPS data, then print error message "Cannot find GPS data",

   (b) If GPS data correctly read, then print out GPS data.

---

4. I suggest you to set up the GPS thing and try again.  I am using Neo-6/7/8M.  If you are using the same thing, I might try to compare and contrast your results.

---

5. Of course you might not have setup your GPS hardware/software correctly, and have a problem getting fix, so you program would not print any GPS data.  You might like to read my test results [Ref 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519711/gps-taking-long-time-to-fix-out-in-the-open/519716#519716) on how to use python to print out Neo-8M GPS results.  Actually the GPS NMEA data file is very simple.  So it should be easy to extract the data, not necessary from Neo-6/7/8M.

---

*Part B - Tips for GPS newbies*

1. The OP follows the video by the Sparklers which uses CLI (Command Line Interface), which is a bit tedious and easy to go wrong for newbies.
2. I would suggest newbies to start with ***Windows ublox u-Centre*** which is GUI (Graphics User Interface) and therefore very user friendly.  Actually you don't any Rpi, just put it away and learn the basics with Windows ublox U-Centre.

---

***References***

(1) [Rpi Neo-6M / Neo-8M GPS Module Setup/Fix/Update Problems (Using Thonny python to print out GPS fixing data) - RpiSE, Asked 2020jun18, Viewed 1k times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/rpi-neo-6m-neo-8m-gps-module-setup-fix-update-problems)

(2) [GPS taking long time to fix out in the open - EESE, Asked 2020sep03, Viewed 2k times](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519711/gps-taking-long-time-to-fix-out-in-the-open/519716#519716)

(3) [How can Rpi listen to a GPS module? - RpiSE, 2020jun02, Viewed 1k times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113057/how-can-rpi-listen-to-a-gps-module/113066#113066)

(4) [YouTube Video on How to use Neo 6M GPS module with Raspberry Pi and Python (11:19 The OP's program) - Sparklers 2019jul23](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8fH0nc9v9Q)

---

Comment: Sure! I would appreciate it if we could compare our GPS results. 2. where can I find the Thonny package management tools? I only used pip. 3. Do you mean I need an else statement? I'm not sure if it's a hardware problem. It works fine when i run it in the terminal by typing ```python gps.py```

Comment: Please read Ref 1 for my Rpi Thonny python IDE GPS results. Cheers.

Comment: I see what you mean now. For some reason, the part with printf(gps) was left out when I copied it to my computer.

Comment: How nice to hear that you are also using Neo GPS sensors.  As suggested in my answer, Neo ulbox u-centre is really newbie friendly.  Happy GPS playing.  Cheers.

Comment: Really appreciate the long detailed answer