# Is this the correct way to connect this set of components (gardening application)

Tags: wiring

The project is one where I want to monitor and log

- Soil pH
- Soil moisture
- Room Temp
- Room Humidity

---

Shown in the diagram are:

**Capacitive soil moisture detector** 3.3-5.5V
[link](https://www.amazon.ca/Gikfun-Capacitive-Corrosion-Resistant-Detection/dp/B07H3P1NRM)

**ADC1115** to convert soil moisture sensor data
[link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085)

**DHT11 Temp/Humidity Sensor** 3.3V 
[link](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/dht11-temperature-humidity-sensor-module.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5raHo4Tf6AIVUPDACh2czgVYEAQYBCABEgIkHPD_BwE)

**Elegoo 8ch relay**
[link](https://www.amazon.ca/ELEGOO-Channel-Optocoupler-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B06XCN5JNH)

**2 Peristaltic Pumps** 12V
[link](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01IUVHB8E)

---

My wiring attempt:

[image: Gardening project]

Thanks for your help, very new to this, but am enjoying the learning process!

Comment: This might help: "What is the correct hardware required to connect multiple analog sensors to a Raspberry Pi 4?":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111213/what-is-the-correct-hardware-required-to-connect-multiple-analog-sensors-to-a-ra. Cheers.

Comment: it looks like the RPi has no power

Comment: I omitted the RPi supply.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @tlfong01 I’ve revised things a bit, just looking for a once over of the circuit diagram to ensure there are no mistakes or oversights.

Comment: the relay board does not share a ground with the RPi

Comment: What have you tried? Does anything work? There is **NO** correct way of connecting that relay module - they are unsuitable for the Pi.

Comment: Hi @Saeven, your project plan looks good overall. As you might have read from my other answer to a similar micro-green project, yours is big project, so take your time and go slowly. Happy learning. Cheers.

Comment: @Milliways the relay does seem to work on its own.  A cursory test to verify on/off is posted here https://youtu.be/KBXcvMfPYqU. Why do you say they are unsuitable?

Comment: @jsotola Do they still need to share a ground, if it is grounded by the separate power supply used to power the relay?

Comment: @Saeven, no direct ground connection is like connecting a lightbulb to one terminal of a battery only ... your relay board works because of some unknown ground loop ... maybe through the power supply, or maybe through the data pins ... does the relay board work if you activate both of the relays?

Comment: @Saeven See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100014/8697 - there are many more references

Comment: @Milliways interesting. I’ll be giving it its own power supply, and am not experiencing the issues in that thread. I am not experiencing any trouble actuating the relay through GPIO

Answer (score 2):

I think you've gotten some good feedback in the comments, but your question about the correct connection or wiring isn't likely to get an answer - at least not a complete one. I say this for two reasons:

1. It seems unlikely that anyone will have experience with each of the sensors you've selected
2. If they did, the answer would be *tedious*

In other words, your question is very **broad**.

I'd suggest that you approach this on an *incremental* basis: Connect one sensor, write some code, test & verify correct operation. If you have problems, than ask a *specific* question re that one sensor (wiring or code or even both).

So - this isn't an answer at all - it's only a suggestion. Also, I've up-voted your question... not because it's a good question (I do feel it's too broad), but  because I'm contemplating a similar project, and I appreciated the links to the different sensors.

Just one other suggestion, and I'll leave you to something more productive :)  You can answer your own question here at SE. As you work through this project, you could even post multiple answers covering different aspects. Just a thought...