# How can Rpi connect to and read the DIY PH-4502C pH Sensor?

Tags: pi-zero-w, software-installation, connection, electronics, monitoring

How can Rpi connect to and read the DIY PH-4502C pH Sensor?

Comment: A couple of years ago I experimented with your pH sensor and found it good.  I will try to make a short answer here. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Pierre Auger, when I answered the question (Ref 1) two years ago, there was only one user guide in Chinese, so everybody got confused. Then I translated the manual to English and also explained how to connect, calibrate, and convert the results. I already compiled a short conversion table. Perhaps you can do more experiments and compile your own conversion table. Happy experiments. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

How can Rpi read DIY PH-4502C pH Sensor?

---

***Answer***

1. DIY PH-4502C pH Sensor has an analog output. So you can use a multimeter to read the analog values and use a voltage to pH values table to find the pH value.  You can also use  Rpi to interface an ADC eg, MCP3008, and convert the ADC results to pH values.
2. I am summarizing some of my findings below.

---

*1. Setting up summary*

---

[image: 4502c module]

---

[image: measure]

---

[image: example reading]

---

[image: conversion table]

---

***References***

(1) [DIY PH-4502C pH Sensor Calibration and ADC using MCP3008, PCF8591, and ADS1115, Asked 2019apr18, Viewed 14k times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96653/ph-4502c-ph-sensor-calibration-and-adc-using-mcp3008-pcf8591-and-ads1115)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Experiment Results*

---

[image: pH table]

---

[image: orange]

---

[image: tea]

---