# Raspberry pi and microbit working together

Tags: gpio

Can I do a pin out from raspberry pi onto a breadboard and have a microbit setup to receive that pin out and have the microbit run a command on pin in?

Or can I have the raspberry pi send a signal to the microbit over USB on a value being true.

Also can the raspberry pi and microbit communicate over bluetooth? Like the raspberry pi sends a command to the microbit and the microbit does a function

Thanks

Comment: "microbit" is a quite generic term, do you mean [this one](https://microbit.org/)? This is a nitpick though, the main problem is that your question is rather vague and non-specific. Can you connect an RPi and microbit? Sure! Will they do what you intend them to do? Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> 1. Can Rpi interface with MicroBit over GPIO?
> 2. Can Rpi interface with MicroBit over Serial?

***Short Answer***

> Yes, no problem at all.  I would suggest to start with UART serial,
>   using Rpi python on one side, and MicroBit MicroPython on the other
>   side.

***Long Answer***

*Brainstorming comments*

> 1. I played with MicroBit a couple of years ago, mainly using microPython.  My MicroBit knowledge is a bit out of date.  I need to
>      google and do some tests to catch up.
> 2. Using Rpi and MicroBit GPIO to communication is possible, but only for very basic communication and control, say this side reading button
>      presses at the other side, or another side blinking LED at this side. 
>      For more complicated things, it is easier to us UART serial, because
>      the handshaking, message sending and receiving protocols are standardized.
> 3. Though both MicroBit and Rpi have I2C and SPI. but usually both behave as masters.  It might be hard to make changes to let two masters to talk
>      together.
> 4. For easy troubleshooting, it a good idea to do 3 steps:

```
     (a) Make sure Rpi UART/serial software/hardware setup/initiation is OK 
         by checking python serial loopback. 

     (b) Make sure MicroBit also OK by microPython serial loopback.

     (c) Make sure WinPC RealTerm 9,600 8N1 can talk to Rpi.

     (d) Make sure RealTerm 9,600 8N1 can talk to MicroBit.

     (e) Now the time has come to let Rpi and MicroBit to talk to each other.
```

> 5. So far I have not read any good tutorials on Rpi talking to MicroBit, but Rpi to Arudino are plenty.  You can easily google, or read the
>      posts in the references below.

***References***

*[BBC micro:bit MicroPython Docs » Microbit Module » UART](https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uart.html)*

*[UART on Micro:Bit - MicroPython Forum](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=3332)*

*[Rpi Talks to Arduino Over UART Serial - Rpi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96184/serial-to-arduino-totally-non-responsive)*

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - MicroBit PinOut*

[image: microbit pinout]

Answer (score 0):

Wiring as shown above would be much easier, though taking up many pins. Bluetooth work better: https://ukbaz.github.io/howto/ubit_workshop.html

however be warned of the long wait time.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/123761)