# How to supply multiple servo motor and dc motor while using gsm module?

Tags: pi-zero, servo, power-management, dc-motor

I've started rc plane but with internet connection instead of regular radio. My plan is using Ai-thinker A6 gsm module so I can use it as live stream camera and control servo together with blynk. Currently I use usb tethering from my android to test it.

As an aeromodel project, I have 3 Tower pro sg90 servo's and will bought dc motor in future. I've successfully control 1 servo but I don't know how can I put the others since I hear direct supply from my pi-zero gpio will broke my pi-zero.

Is there any module or what can I do to supplied power for my 3servos and a dc motor? I am afraid it will conflict with gsm module if I use a servo-control module like adafruit 16 channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Answer***

*Just a couple of suggestions:*

1. I use Lipo power bank to power 3+ sg90/mg995/mg996 servos, and dc motors.
2. I use SIM7600's using USB UART ports not sharing with Rpi GPIOs handling servos.
3. I use Rpi3B+, Rpi4B as development machine, and RpiZ/W on the drone, this way saves much prototyping time.
4. Using 16 Channel PWM/servo module is an overkill.

---

***References***

(1) [How can Rpi4B use UART to read and analyze received data at a 3DR FPV Air Radio Module? (Q&A)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105223/how-can-rpi4b-use-uart-to-read-and-analyze-received-data-at-a-3dr-fpv-air-radio/105489#105489)

(2) [How can Rpi4B use UART to read and analyze received data at a 3DR FPV Air Radio Module? (Chat Record - 24 days long! :))](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/100706/2019/11/5)

(3) [18650 (Lipo battery) - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/18650)

(4) [LiPo (Lithium polymer battery) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Lipo power bank for Neo GPS*

[image: lipo power bank]

---

Comment: Do u use any module to supply all of your servo and dc motors?

Comment: Quick reply - Ah, for TowerPro MG966 servos, I have a ***7V 21A** PSU.  For BLDC motors, I have 24V/36V PSU. For microstepping motors, I have 24V to 48V PSUs. For more details, you might like to search EESE , RpiSE, and Rpi.Org.Forum for my other projects on the above motors.