# how to enable ttyAMA0 on raspberrypi 4 and how to make it to communicate with pixhawk?

Tags: serial, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to make communication between raspberrypi4 and pixhawk board to control the drone using dronekit library and to get telemetry info. I have used pin 14 and 15 for serial communication. But its not working and I can't access the ttyAMA0. It always gives the error as such directory is not found. I don't know what is the problem and where to start. if anyone know how to do it please help me by giving the step by step procedure to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled the serial link with `sudo raspi-config`?

Comment: It is hardly surprising that you can't use ttyAMA0 because it is connected to Bluetooth.

Comment: This might help - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105223/how-can-rpi4b-use-uart-to-read-and-analyze-received-data-at-a-3dr-fpv-air-radio/105489#105489

Comment: Your question is lacking of details: how you try to access the port, what error you get and what did you tried to troubleshoot it.